# How to add Expressions on EntityQuery in Drupal 9

Tags: drupal

I am using Entity Query to select nodes of two different types say `article` and `page`. The fetching seems to be working but now i have to apply sorting to it. Both the content types have different date field say `field_date_1` and `field_date_2`. Now i know i could do this by adding expression`$query->addExpression('COALESCE( field_date_1, field_date_2)', 'Date');` in SQL query and sort on `$query->sort('Date', 'DESC');`

But, `addExpression()` or adding `COALESCE` to sort() in Entity Query is throwing `Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Query::addExpression()`

So, could anyone help me with how to apply sort on more than 2 date fields or how to add an Expression.

Answer (score 0):

This has helped me:

Add tag to the query:

$query->addTag('my_module_tag');

And add expressions in the module file by implementing hook_query_TAG_alter() -

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter().
 */
function hook_query_my_module_tag_alter(Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {
    $query->addExpression('COALESCE( field_date_1, field_date_2)', 'Date');
}
```